# Registration Endpoint in Xero API

Tags: xero-api

After I explored the API from XERO, I cannot find the Endpoint that is used for registration.

Where can I find the registration endpoint in Xero API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to build an integration you first have to [sign up](https://www.xero.com/signup/api/) as a xero user then log in to [app.xero.com](https://app.xero.com/Application/Add) to create your app and get your credentials.